# Control json_format.MessageToJson property names

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf with a field:
string my_field = 1;

I'm using google.protobuf.json_format to convert this to json.

The output json property name is:
{
"myfield": "hello world"
}

Is there any way to control the property name when converting using json_format?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [url](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat.java), initiate the Printer with the property preservingProtoFieldNames to true which should preserve the original proto field names as defined in the .proto file rather than converting them to lowerCamelCase. I am guessing you are using python but I guess the supported libraries should support it too.

```
JsonFormat.Printer  preservingProtoFieldNames()
Creates a new JsonFormat.Printer that is configured to use the original proto field names as defined in the .proto file rather than converting them to lowerCamelCase.
```